# android model view presenter/controller examples

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvp

are there any good examples or tutorials on how best to structure an android applications anywhere?

am new to java and android and i've built winforms apps using passive and supervising controller variants of model view presenter and model view controller in asp.net but not really seen any examples or code on android that use these sorts of patterns.

how do people structure decent size android apps out there in the wild. are there any best practices or should i be sticking rigidly to official android documentation.

Comment: Ironically, I asked the same question. Check out my answer for the link.

Comment: Fair enough about the links to other questions but would still love to see good examples or hear how people actually structure things.

Comment: Or some links to open source apps that are considered to be really well structured and put together that sort of thing

Comment: Check my update. There are some helpful videos that should explain what you're wanting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try with the following two examples. I've found them useful in understanding how MVP might apply to Android applications.

http://web.archive.org/web/20120524010643/http://chicagoandroid.com/forum/topics/mvp-android-perspective

http://web.archive.org/web/20130525044856/http://jamespeckham.com/Blog/10-11-21/MVP_on_Android.aspx

Comment: @Mohit: The mentioned Google IO video is more about User Interaction/ User eXperience design patterns, than (Graphical) User Iterfaces design patterns to which MVP/ MVC belong.

Comment: @JDPeckham well, it's a good example that goes to the point, so ... :)

Comment: http://www.jamespeckham.com/blog/10-11-21/MVP_on_Android.aspx is Broken

Comment: There must have been a major re-building of the blog. Maybe @JDPeckham can help

Comment: Wayback machine link for jamespeckham's dead link: http://web.archive.org/web/20120904080602/http://jamespeckham.com/blog/10-11-21/MVP_on_Android.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Also [Mosby](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) implements an MVP pattern plus other things, but it is modular enough so that you can use only the MVP part and forget about the rest.

There is also a nice blog post covering the motivations and choices of this [library](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/index.html). There you will find the answers to all of your questions. And MVC is already present in Android. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android). The videos [here](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=M1ZBjlCRfz0) can explain what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I created an application to manage my expenses. It is built using MVP pattern. I have explained it in [this post](http://www.singhajit.com/mvp-in-android).