# How Spring MVC architecture can be used in android

Tags: android, spring

How Spring MVC architecture can be used in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Spring Android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android),
Spring Android is an extension of the Spring Framework that aims to simplify the development of native Android applications.

Answer (score 2):

A better question would be how to use Android to contact a Spring backend using Spring MVC.  You may want to look into other design patterns/frameworks in Android.

[android model view presenter/controller examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320141/android-model-view-presenter-controller-examples)