# Android MVP Samples

Tags: android, architecture, mvp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android model view presenter/controller examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320141/android-model-view-presenter-controller-examples)

Can anyone give the example to make android application using MVP Framework? I already google'd and didn't find the one that make me understand the architectures of MVP in Android. Thanks.

Comment: I accidentally voted to close this. I wanna take my action back :(

Comment: @nawfal Where the "close" button is, now you see a "reopen" button. Use that to cancel your close vote.

Comment: I've started writing a blog on the topic if you're still interested: http://cj65535.blogspot.com.au/2017/03/a-simple-mvp-framework-for-android.html

Comment: [this](https://academy.realm.io/posts/eric-maxwell-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-on-android/) is the best explanation to architecture design pattern in Android I have read.

Answer (score 5):

This is the [best example](http://magenic.com/Blog/Post/6) that i found when learning MVP.

There are tons of examples on the internet. Just keep googling, you will find plenty.

Also, this is a [duplicate of this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320141/android-model-view-presenter-controller-examples). Try this post too for examples.